# How to Count quantity of my QuerySet. Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

Well, i have the following function:

```
employees_birthday = Employees.objects.filter(EmployeeDataNasc__gte=first_day, EmployeeDataNasc__lte=last_day)
```

It serves to return employees born between the dates. She returns:

```
<QuerySet [<Employees: Alberto Santos>, <Employees: Josney Arman>]>
```

**But, I would just like to display the number of employees in the QuerySet, i.e. make a Count function.**

Can someone help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to display the `Employees` anyway, then it is better to use `len(…)`. This will fetch the `Employees` in memory, and return the number of `Employees`:

```
employees_birthday = Employees.objects.filter(
    EmployeeDataNasc__range=(first_day, last_day)
)
number_of_birthdays = len(employee_birthdays)
```

if you however plan to *only* render the *number* of `Employees`, then you use [**`.count()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#count), since this will prevent fetching the items in memory.